# Asterisk: How to connect called Party to another Destination

Tags: asterisk

I need to connect the called party to another destination on an Asterisk.

Simple situation:

Inbound call is coming in, answered, welcome prompt, gets connected by the DIAL command to destination 1 (agent 1st level support).

Agent 1st level has to consult agent 2nd level, while inbound call is on hold/parked. In some situations the inbound call then has to be connected to the 2nd level agent.

Any idea how I can control the call to the called party (agent 1st level)? Isn't it just a call transfer situation with a conversation between the forwarding and the second destination?

I am using phpagi so I can send all commands from php scripts - but it doesn't make any difference to dialplan commands.

Thank you for your ideas and help

Kim

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that from AGI, becuase it have no control while in Dial command

You can use transfer from softphone or AMI action Redirect.